# How to add hyperlink to image in canvas element?

Tags: html, image, canvas, hyperlink

I am dynamically adding multiple images to a HTML5 canvas element. I want to hyperlink those images. I have tried different ways but it's not working for me. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Please include the code you tried with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. Here is the [[DEMO]](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/XXBPA/1/)

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx;
var linkText="http://google.com";
var linkX=5;
var linkY=15;
var linkHeight=10;
var linkWidth;
var inLink = false;

// draw the balls on the canvas
function draw(){
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  // check if supported
  if(canvas.getContext){

    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    //clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //draw the link
    ctx.font='10px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0000ff";
    ctx.fillText(linkText,linkX,linkY);
    linkWidth=ctx.measureText(linkText).width;

    //add mouse listeners
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", on_mousemove, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click, false);

  }
}

//check if the mouse is over the link and change cursor style
function on_mousemove (ev) {
  var x, y;

  // Get the mouse position relative to the canvas element.
  if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { //for firefox
    x = ev.layerX;
    y = ev.layerY;
  }
  x-=canvas.offsetLeft;
  y-=canvas.offsetTop;

  //is the mouse over the link?
  if(x>=linkX && x <= (linkX + linkWidth) && y<=linkY && y>= (linkY-linkHeight)){
      document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
      inLink=true;
  }
  else{
      document.body.style.cursor = "";
      inLink=false;
  }
}

//if the link has been clicked, go to link
function on_click(e) {
  if (inLink)  {
    window.location = linkText;
  }
}

draw();
```

Comment: Demo not found. Broken link. Please correct if possible.

Comment: Works great! Thanks for providing this solution.

Comment: Love to see the working demo. I am taking a different approach by embedding  color coded pins on top of images. The type of link that the pin represents determines the colour of the pin head. The pins are dragged onto the image via JQuery and the position of the pin recorded in real time in the database together with the hyperlink and type for the pin.The when loading the image, I place pins according to their type on the canvas layer over the image with the positions recorded in that database.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to add a hyperlink to an individual canvas image because those images become part of the single canvas element.

The solution is to detect a click event in JavaScript, determine where the cursor is and whether it's over an image, then change the page accordingly.

Comment: So we have to find out the coordinates of the images and then we need to set hyperlinks accordingly to the coordinates position.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx;
var linkText="http://google.com";
var linkX=5;
var linkY=15;
var linkHeight=10;
var linkWidth;
var inLink = false;

// draw the balls on the canvas
function draw(){
  canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  // check if supported
  if(canvas.getContext){

    ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    //clear canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    //draw the link
    ctx.font='10px sans-serif';
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0000ff";
    ctx.fillText(linkText,linkX,linkY);
    linkWidth=ctx.measureText(linkText).width;

    //add mouse listeners
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", on_mousemove, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("click", on_click, false);

  }
}

//check if the mouse is over the link and change cursor style
function on_mousemove (ev) {
  var x, y;

  // Get the mouse position relative to the canvas element.
  if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { //for firefox
    x = ev.layerX;
    y = ev.layerY;
  }
  x-=canvas.offsetLeft;
  y-=canvas.offsetTop;

  //is the mouse over the link?
  if(x>=linkX && x <= (linkX + linkWidth) && y<=linkY && y>= (linkY-linkHeight)){
      document.body.style.cursor = "pointer";
      inLink=true;
  }
  else{
      document.body.style.cursor = "";
      inLink=false;
  }
}

//if the link has been clicked, go to link
function on_click(e) {
  if (inLink)  {
    window.location = linkText;
  }
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width=500 height=500 style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Here is a working link.

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting an answer. Please consider adding context to your answer's code.